# Print time from external server in bash

Tags: linux, bash, time, synchronize, ntp

I'd like to know if it's possible to simply retrieve a `Unix timestamp` from an external server (using `NTP`, I suppose). I know there's `ntpd`, which will update the current system time to the time given by an `NTP` server, but I only want to *read* the `timestamp`. Is it possible using a `Bash` command in Linux? If not, I guess I'll just have to write a Python (or something) app to get it and print it on the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some servers provide the `daytime` daemon which can give you what you want, in textual form anyway.

Try:

```
telnet SERVER daytime
```

on your favorite `SERVER`.

Example transcript:

```
pax$ telnet time.nist.gov daytime
Trying 192.43.244.18...
Connected to time.nist.gov.
Escape character is '^]'.

55860 11-10-26 06:33:38 12 0 0 438.2 UTC(NIST) *
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you *own* the server and can set up ssh access (or, worst case, rsh access), you can run the `date` command on the remote machine, i.e.

```
ssh user@remoteHost "date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"
20111026.090705
```

You can give the `date` cmd lots of options to format the output just like you would like it, use `man date` and look at the end of the document for examples. Note in my example that %Y is the 4 digit year, %m is two digit month, %d is two digit day, %H %M %S are two digit hr, minute and seconds.

The remoteHost can be an IP address or a servername that you have a network path to.

I hope this helps.